# Cloudfront: every resource request is routed via a different cloudfront subdomain

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

When requesting a JavaScript resource (libraries.js) via the browser or cURL, I get a consistent Cloudfront cache miss (X-Cache: Miss from Cloudfront). The item's max-age, expires and cache-control headers are all set correctly.

When I inspect the Responses I can see that all request responses have a different value for the **Via** attribute:

```
curl -kv http://example.org/libraries.js (x5)
```

### Response 1

```
Cache-Control: max-age=172800
Expires: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 15:00:24 GMT
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 37af1xxxxxx8abe6.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

### Response 2

```
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 1b52axxxxxxf467a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

### Response 3

```
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 ae162xxxxxxec67a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

### Response 4

```
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 ff555xxxxxx6cc33.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

### Response 5

```
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1  b9a8cxxxxxxf1ec8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

Every sub-domain seems to be different on every request. 
When I request the resource directly from the node address (xxxxx.cloudfront.net) instead of my own domain, the Cache is Hit successfully, which leads me to believe that every via address is in fact a different edge location.

What is the role of the sub-domains in Cloudfront? Is this a dynamic variable that redirects the request to Cloudfront, or is this in fact the location of an edge cache?

It appears to me that none of the requests is a cache hit because the request is not in the sub-domain's cache yet and since it keeps requesting via different URLs it is rarely served from cache.

In the Amazon Cloudfront documentation I can only find documentation regarding custom sub-domains.

Comment: I am working on an answer for this, but would you please confirm some of your cache behavior settings, first?  For [Object Caching](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesObjectCaching), did you choose `Customize`, or did yoi choose `Use Origin Cache Headers`?  If `Customize`, what are the values for your minimum, maximum, and default TTLs?  Also, have you changed any of these values recently?

Comment: Minimum TTL: 0
Maximum TTL: 31536000
Default TTL: 86400

Did not change the values recently

Comment: So `Use Origin Cache Headers` is **not** selected?

Comment: Correct, it is not selected

Comment: Sorry I haven't added a response yet. I can confirm that `Via:` is definitely *not* an edge or edge server identifier, but appears to be an opaque request id that simply looks like a domain name.  Observing on both ends, the same string is sent to origin and viewer, but it varies even with cache hits that are obviously coming from the same edge.  I suspect you have a config issue, but am unsure what.  Are you [forwarding any headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders) to the origin server?